# Backup Data on Android Recovery Mode!

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, reboot

I am Asus Zenfone 5 (lollipop 5.0). It is not turned on because if affected when try rooting software(iRoot). I need to backup my internal and other app data. In recovery mode, there is no option to backup my data. I have important data on my internal memory(16GB). Please help me to backup data.Thanks in Advance...

Recovery mode option:

```
reboot system now
apply update from ADB
wipe data/factory reset 
wipe cache partition
reboot to bootloader
power down 
view recovery logs
```

Comment: You need a custom recovery (TWRP, CWM, Philz etc.) in order to backup your data. The stock recovery merely allows you to wipe the device or flash updates.

Comment: I am already set my mobile not turn on. Then how can try these?

Comment: xda-developers.com is a pretty good source for Android related things like recoveries, custom ROMs etc. I found TWRP for your phone here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/recovery-twrp-2-8-6-0-asus-zenfone-5-t3136263. Make sure to read the post *before* you do anything to your phone. I take no responsibility for any damage caused to your phone through any of the methods described in the post.